# Updating a webpage in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, client-server

I have a web page open on a mobile, the same page is open on a Desktop, how can I enter a keystroke on the desktop in a text area that will display in real time on the mobile device?

I have thought about adding an on key event that sends the keystroke to the server, but how can I update the page on the mobile device to display the same keystroke?

To be honest, this is a much-simplified version of the application but at its basics, this is how the process works, the keystroke actually defines an event on the page, but firing that event needs to be replicated on all browsers viewing the page.

How can the same page listen to the server to update the page from the keystroke as quick as possible?

Thanks in advance fr any help given.

Comment: google "realtime messaging" or "realtime apps". that should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: @JefM To add o his comment, check out Firebase.

Comment: there are multiple ways to achieve this.. for basics set a interval of few seconds and hit your server via  ajax call and display... for massive usage socket.io would be my choice ;)

Comment: if you need an example for how ajax will work here... let me know what all have you done till now

Comment: Thanks everyone, @Aniket I have not used socket.io before.  This is what I am hoping to achieve, I have a two 3d cubes spinning using css, with jQuery I can adjust the position of the cubes to give the impression of camera movement,  So a person wears a phone in a VR unit with the web page displayed, have the same (or a different page) open and use the keyboard to send commands to the page held in the vr unit, the keystrokes tell jQuery which value to adjust, I have the css and the cubes initial state ready and I am writing the jquery to change positions,  on the same page

Comment: This 10 minutes tutorial helps understand the concept easily.. http://socket.io/get-started/chat/